# Render has a purple light

Tags: rendering

I recently started seeing a purple light in my render and don't know why this happened all of a sudden.

I don't think it's a missing material because it appears across several surface areas.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Do you have any HDRI?

Comment: please provide your blend file... just an image is here too less information

Comment: It looks like a missing texture in the world shader, creating purple ambient lighting, which is coloring some surfaces purple. Go to shader editor and change from object to world and check if the environment texture is missing.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that was exactly my problem. I had accidentally deleted the HDRI.
It works again. You've saved me hours of debugging.

Comment: Glad you got the answer! THIS IS A JOKE on my immediate thought when seeing the question: “There are good renders when one wakes up with tea, and a purple light. Then there are renders with no tea, or no HDRI at all. Mornings when blender realizes it’s file has been lost. Deleted by the user. Possibly forever.”  -Leo’s Fortune (modified)